# References on tetrahedra

Tags: reference-request

I’ve recently been interested in tetrahedra.

What made me interested is the “fascinating” resemblence between tetrahedra and triangles.

For instance in a trerectangular tetrahedron the square of the area  of the “hypotenuse” face equals the sum of the squares of the other three faces, which clearly is a 3D version of the Pythagorean theorem .

There are other fascinating parts about the circumscribed and inscribed spheres, the condition the “hypotenuse” face in a trerectangular tetrahedron must be acute.

I’ve also come across imaginary numbers ,throughout my research on Google!!

What I ask for is as follows :
A textbook/article/part of a texbook (any referenc) which discusses tetrahedra and their “amazing” properties.

Comment: This is not my goal of posting this question ,but I would also be glad if someone explains the “magic” between triangles and tetrahedra (For instance  the Pythagorean theorem and its 3D counterpart)

Comment: At [hedronometry.com](http://hedronometry.com) (basically a link to some blog posts), I've compiled a few notes about tetrahedra (both Euclidean and non-) ... in particular, the dimensionally-enhanced trigonometry of tetrahedra (hence, "hedronometry") that includes not only the  Pythagorean relation (aka, [de Gua's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem)) but also Laws of Cosines  (which introduce the surprisingly-useful notion of tetrahedral "pseudofaces"). Please forgive the embarrassing roughness of older notes; I was using them primarily to practice TeX formatting. :)